# Deserialize Json String into from Map<String,List<CustomWrapperClass>> in apex

Tags: apex, json

I am currently working on a Lightning component where the data that I am passing from my apex controller ( in the `doInit()` ) is in the form of `Map<String,List<CustomWrapper>>`.

When Some modifications to the records are made, I have to pass this whole Map from component to apex controller.

To achieve this, I have first converted this map into Json using stringify() in my JS Controller and then passed this string version of json to my apex method.

Now, when I receive this string in the apex method, I am unable to convert it back in the form of `Map<String,List<CustomWrapper>>`.

How do I do this?

P.S. - CustomWrapper is a wrapper class with some string variables in it.

Comment: Could you provide code snippets of what did you do to this point?

Comment: Make an [edit] to your post to include some raw json (for other users to try and parse), the wrapper class definition (so we can repo it on our orgs), the code you're using to try and parse the data, and any error messages reported by the console. Without this, any answer given will be either guesswork, or  example code of how you could do something, but not whats wrong with whatever code you've written.

Comment: Sure.Thanks for the suggestion.I will take that in mind from now on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this, I used the approach of JSONToApex.I parsed the String json and it gave me the stub that I needed to store my response.Below is the structure:

```
public class ResponseResult {
    public String name;
    public List<Bookings> bookings;

    public class Bookings {
        public Boolean checked;
        public Boolean selectionNotAllowed;
        public String strName;
        public String strServiceName;
        public String strSupplierName;
        public String strEndDate;
        public String strQuantity;
        public String strStartDate;
        public String strStatus;
        public String strStartTime;
    }

    public static List<ResponseResult> parse(String jsonString) {
        return (List<ResponseResult>)JSON.deserialize(jsonString, List<ResponseResult>.class);
    }
}
```

I used that stub in my apex controller to parse json which gave me list of ResponseResult records:

```
List<ResponseResult> lstResults = ResponseResult.parse(mapRecords);
```

Hopefully, this would help folks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSON.deserialize in you apex Class. Hope this example will help you.

**Apex controller**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void onInit(String memberJson){
  Map<String,List<CustomWrapper>> myMap = 
  (Map<String,List<CustomWrapper>>)JSON.deserialize(memberJson, 
  Map<String,List<CustomWrapper>>.class);
}
```

Comment: I had tried this approach the first time itself but it gave me MALFORMED JSON Error.But technically, I did similar stuff.The only difference is that I created another class to store the parsed json into collection of objects.